# $mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Information');

Tags: php

Обратный адрес. 
Письмо отправляется но почему то обратного адреса нет.. .

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Information');
```

Comment: и это вся инфа, которую вы можете предоставить?

Comment: Да все. Уже решил проблему=) 
И она была именно в этой строке.